# Kiel (idiomate) diri "Merry Christmas" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom, festo, saluto

Kiel saluti en Esperanto referente kristnaska festo?

Mi nur vidis "Feliĉan Kristnaskon". Ĉu aliaj tradukoj ankaŭ estas ĝusta, eksemple "Ĝojan Kristnaskon" aŭ "Gajan Kristnaskon"?

Ĉu "Feliĉan Kristnaskon" estas la idiomata saluto, same kiel "Happy Christmas" en la angla aŭ "Fröhliche Weihnachten" en la germana ne estas malĝusta, sed "Merry Christmas" / "Frohe Weihnachten" estas tio saluto, kio oni uzas la plej ofte en tioj lingvoj?

---

Other than [How to say "Season's greetings" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5070/1576), this question is specifically about Christmas greetings (i.e. not necessarily religion-neutral). So while it may or may not have the same answer(s) as that other question, it is a different question and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Krom *Feliĉan Kristnaskon* ekzistas ankaŭ *Feliĉan Julon*.

> [PIV] **Julo**. Festo de la vintra solstico: *Jularbo*. ☞ Kristnasko.
>
> [ReVo] **Julo**. Mezvintra festo en Nordeŭropaj landoj: *Julo ... estas en
>   la skandinaviaj lingvoj la kaj kristana kaj nekristana vorto por la
>   festo, kiun oni celebras baldaŭ post la kaprikorna solstico; feliĉan
>   Julon!*.

Ŝajnas al mi ke *Feliĉan Julon* estas pli religie neŭtrala formo.

Comment: Tre interesa kaj utila, dankon! Sed mi eksplicite demandis pri kristnaska saluto (do, ne religie neŭtrala). Ĉar religie neŭtrala saluto estas ankaŭ interesa temo, mi nun demandis [novan demandon pri ĝi](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5070/1576).

Comment: En iuj lingvoj oni esprimas la kristnaskan saluton dirante _Feliĉan Julon_. Ekz. oni diras en la dana _Glædelig Jul_, en la sveda _God Jul_, en la finna _Hyvää Joulua_, kun la sama signifo kiel la angla _Merry Christmas_. Eble _Feliĉan Julon_ ŝajnas pli religie neŭtrala en Esperanto, sed verŝajne ne en tiuj lingvoj. Por mi _Feliĉan_, _Ĝojan_ aŭ _Gajan Kristnaskon_ estas same bonaj kaj signifas same kiel _Feliĉan_, _Ĝojan_ aŭ _Gajan Julon_.