# How to say "Season's greetings" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom, festo, saluto

How do you greet / wish a good time in Esperanto referring to the December festive season but **without referring to any specific religion** or religious holiday (like Christmas, Hanukah, etc.)?

(I.e., what is nowadays often done in English with neologisms like "Season's greetings".)

---

Other than [Kiel (idiomate) diri "Merry Christmas" en Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5068/1576), this question is specifically about **religion-neutral** greetings. So while it may or may not have the same answer(s) as that other question, it is a different question and not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kiel (idiomate) diri "Merry Christmas" en Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/kiel-idiomate-diri-merry-christmas-en-esperanto)

Comment: Mi malkonsentas pri ĉi-tio esti duplikato de https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/kiel-idiomate-diri-merry-christmas-en-esperanto. (Ambaŭ estas miaj demandoj.) https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/kiel-idiomate-diri-merry-christmas-en-esperanto eksplicite estas pri Kristnasko, sed ĉi-tiu demando ekspicite estas pri religie neŭtralaj salutoj.

Comment: Mi scias, ke tiu demando temas pri Kristnasko, sed la respondo al ĝi enhavas bondeziron, kiu al mi ŝajnas religineŭtrala. Laŭ la tie donitaj difinoj _Julo_ referencas simple feston ĉirkaŭ la vintra solstico. Ke similan terminon oni uzas en aliaj lingvoj por referenci Kristnaskon, ne tiom gravas laŭ mi, ĉar la signifo en Esperanto rilatas nur al la periodo ĉirkaŭ la vintra solstico.

Comment: While the same answer(s) might be correct for both questions due to how the topic is handled in Esperanto language and Esperanto culture, that doen't mean they're essentially the same question. They are obviously related, but they _could_ have different answers and even if they don't (which we don't know yet, as they only got one answer each, yet) whether they do or don't have the same answer would be unclear to everyone not already knowing the answers.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes perfect sense. I had not considered it in that way. I have retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

Mi proponas "Feliĉajn Festojn!"

Mi pensas ke se vi volas esprimon por ĉiuj festoj en decembro, tiu ĉi esprimo servas por diri tion.

Comment: Is that term specific to the conglomerate of various December festivities or could you say "Feliĉajn Festojn!" before/during e.g. Easter or Durga Puja season, too?

Comment: This could refer to any group of holidays